# Setting a common description in magento

Tags: php, magento

Im hoping someone can help me here.

I want to add a default bit of text/html at the bottom of every description but be able to set the top paragraph differently for each product.

Basically I have some general information text to add to each product description.

I would personally try and use a php include for this so that i can get each product to reference one document for the general information so i only have to update one source for future edits.

I just dont know how best to achieve this, I am new to magento.

Any help would be amazing.

Regards, 
Jake

Comment: For that common text, you can create a system config field. refer any system.xml file of a module to understand how to create a field. later you can use `Mage::getStoreConfig('id_here');` to fetch the content.

Comment: If you need to set those description individually for each product, I think you need to go for setting a new attribute and configure it with Products in admin.

Comment: Guys thank you for your responses.  Mr_green, I just put mage:: code straight into the description field?  

programmer, I have looked a little into the product attribute thing, I want the extra information to appear under the main description, is there something in the attributes that will allow me to do that and use a standard piece of text when i create the product? that would be the easiest option but its a little confusing to me.  thanks for your help